# Set AutoFac to use PropertiesAutowired(true) as default?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container

Is there a way i can set AutoFac to use PropertiesAutowired(true) to be the default for all types being registered.

i.e. I dont want to use ".PropertiesAutowired(true)" all the time

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Logger>()
    .PropertiesAutowired(true)
    .SingleInstance();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done with a module, e.g.

```
class InjectPropertiesByDefaultModule : Autofac.Module {
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistration registration,
        IComponentRegistry registry) {
            registration.Activating += (s, e) => {
                e.Context.InjectProperties(e.Instance);
            };
    }
}
```

Then:

```
builder.RegisterModule<InjectPropertiesByDefaultModule>();
```

I think you might be misunderstanding the `true` paramerter to `PropertiesAutowired` - it determines how circular dependencies are supported and should probably remain `false`. To emulate the `true` setting you can attach to `Activated` instead of `Activating` above.

However, if at all possible, use constructor injection even for "optional" dependencies like your `ILog`. It leads to cleaner components (e.g. fields can be made `readonly`) and dependencies are more understandable (they're all in the constructor, and there's no guessing about the meaning of individual properties.)

Only consider using property injection when there are multiple configurations of the application and in some configurations the dependency will be truly absent.

Even in these cases, the "Null Object" pattern is usually a better fit.

Comment: Also - if you're integrating Log4Net, take a look at: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Log4NetIntegration :)

Comment: Thanks Simon - should have been "registration" - fixed now.

Comment: Doh, nice one, we shouldn't underestimate the power of Autofac modules :) My ignorant answer is hereby modified.

Comment: This code snippet does not seem to work with Autofac 6.3.0

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. Though, if you register types in bulk or by convention it will be easier, e.g. using `builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(..)`.

**Update**: Yes there is, see [@Nicholas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384812/set-autofac-to-use-propertiesautowiredtrue-as-default/3392396#3392396).