# How to resolve property injection with Autofac?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, autofac, property-injection

I have an MVC web app which uses Autofac to inject services in controllers.

**The problem:** I am trying to do property injection on a service and it fails (the property is always null).

**What I expect:**
I expect to have the property initialized properly (not null) by Autofac.

**Example:**

- I'm trying to inject the AliasesService as IAliasesService into controllers.
- The AliasesService depends on MailService.
- MailService is a property of AliasesService.
- The AliasesService is properly instantiated and passed to MyController.
- The MailService is NOT properly instantied and set to the property of AliasesService

Controller:

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    private IAliasesService AliasesService { get; set; }

    public MyController(IAliasesService aliasesService)
    {
        AliasesService = aliasessService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = aliasesService.GetUserRoles();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).PropertiesAutowired();

builder.RegisterType<MailService>().As<IMailService>();
builder.RegisterType<AliasesService>().As<IAliasesService>().PropertiesAutowired();

var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

AliasesService:

```
public class AliasesService
{
     public IMailService MailService { get; set; }

     public Dictionary<int,string> GetUserRoles()
     {
          MailService.SendMail("method GetUserRoleshas been called");
          return null;
     }
}
```

**Worth mentioning:**

- if I try to do property injection for controllers it works as expected
- constructor injection works but I need property injection.

**What other things I tried with no success:**

## 1

```
builder.RegisterType<MailService>()
       .As<IMailService>();
builder.Register(c => new AliasesService() 
       { 
           MailService = c.Resolve<IMailService>() 
        })
       .As<IAliasesService>();
```

## 2

```
builder.RegisterType<MailService>()
       .As<IMailService>();
builder.RegisterType<AliasesService>()
       .WithProperty("MailService", new MailService())
       .As<IAliasesService>();
```

**Minimal example:**

```
using Autofac;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public interface IBar
    {    
    }

    public class Bar: IBar
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public Bar()
        {
            Text = "Hello world!";
        }
    }

    public interface IFoo
    {
    }

    public class Foo: IFoo
    {
        public IBar Bar { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<Bar>().As<IBar>();
            builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>().PropertiesAutowired();

            var container = builder.Build();

            var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Alternative solution:**

For the minimal example Autofac works but in the context of controllers I still did not managed to make it work as expected so I gave up on using it as I wasted too much time. I'm using Castle Windsor for now and it does everything I need, thank you for the support.

Comment: What doesn't work? Looks like nothing wrong with your code(apart from you have multiple registration of same abstraction). Post a short but complete sample which demonstrates the problem. What is the type of `MailService` property? `MailService` or `IMailService` ?

Comment: `MailService` is a property of `DbRespository` or `AliasesService` ? (I think it is a mistake in your code sample). All the tried solution should works. Could you share code of your controllers and services ? (only the constructor and properties)

Comment: The statements from above are what I tried.
I'm getting a null reference instead of a required instance.

Comment: DbRepository is just another dependency of AliasesService which is satisfied by constructor. I'm simplify the code.

Comment: For example, with this line:

builder.RegisterType<AliasesService>()
       .As<IAliasesService>()
       .PropertiesAutowired();

Looking at the doc, it should do the trick, but it doesn't because at runtime I have "null" value for the property MailService in the AliasesService.

Comment: You didn't show code with actual injections. Anyway, on a hunch, I suspect you don't register the controllers to have PropertiesAutowired. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384812/set-autofac-to-use-propertiesautowiredtrue-as-default and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894458/autofac-inject-properties-into-a-asp-net-mvc-controller (answer from nickvane).

Comment: When are you encountering the nullref exception ? Are you using the property inside a constructor ? By the way,  could you share code of your controllers and services ? (only the constructor and properties) It will help us what is going wrong because everything looks OK

Comment: @JacekGorgoń I do register controllers with PropertiesAutowired and for controllers works just fine (I also stated this in the 'Worth mentioning' section) but the issue refers to a property of a service not a controller.

Comment: @CyrilDurand I added some code, let me know if you see anything wrong.

Comment: @user2704 It seems that you register your controller twice but this should not be a problem. Could you share your `AliasesService` class ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand Added snippet of class.

Comment: Can the On Hold status be removed?

Comment: @user2704 everything looks OK. Could you add breakpoints on constructor and setter and looks at the call stack to check if Autofac build these types ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand Constructor of AliasesService is called, constructor of MailService is not called.

Comment: Is the pasted registration code complete? There is at least one known issue related to interceptors colliding with property injection causing them to fail, but you don't seem to be using interceptors...

Comment: @JacekGorgoń yes, everything works except property injection for services

Comment: This code looks good. Can you create a minimal repro and upload it somwhere?

Answer (score 1):

On your minimal code sample the property *Bar* is declared of type `Bar` which is not registered. The declared property type should be registered in order to let *Autofac* resolve it. You should change the type of the property to `IBar` or register `Bar` as `Bar`

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public IBar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
builder.RegisterType<Bar>().As<Bar>();
```

Comment: This is true, but the minimal repro is inconsistent with AliasesService code above that injects IMailService (not MailService). @user2704: please clarify which code snipped is the one you used.
Also, you can use ``AsSelf()``.

Comment: It was a typo, I corrected the code and added more details.
Thank you for the support guys.

Answer (score 1):

Your minimal example works fine, Foo resolves with a Bar instance injected.

While it's not too helpful, your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

hmm your example is wrong because AliasesService does not implement Interface IAliasesService, but I think that's a typo.

Your MAilService implementation is missing. PropertiesAutowired() silently fails if there are dependencies that it can't resolve.

So your problem probably lies in MailService